# ¿Cómo calcular mi edad en horas, minutos y segundos?

Tags: java

Debo calcular mi edad en años, meses, días, horas, minutos y segundos. Solo he podido calcular años, meses y días. ¿Cómo podría calcular en horas, minutos y segundos?

```
package age;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.Period;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Age {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter your birthdate:");
        System.out.println("Year: ");
        int year = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Month: ");
        int month = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Day: ");
        int day = sc.nextInt();

        LocalDate today = LocalDate.now();
        LocalDate birthdate = LocalDate.of(year, month, day);

        Period p = Period.between(birthdate, today);

        System.out.println("I am " + p.getYears() + " years, " + p.getMonths() + " months, " + p.getDays() + " days old.");       

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usa la libreria

> TimeUnit

```
    import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
    .
    .
      long segundos = TimeUnit.DAYS.toSeconds(tusDias);
      long minutos =TimeUnit.DAYS.toMinutes(tusDias);
      long horas = TimeUnit.DAYS.toHours(tusDias);
```

Comment: No es el uso más completo de  `TimeUnit` , lo que realizas aquí fácil se puede realizar sin usar clases  `Horas = tuDias*24` `Minutos = tuDias*1440` `Segundos = tuDias*86400`

Comment: Tambien es valida esa respuesta, claro yo me siento mas comodo en usar TimeUnit.

Answer (score 1):

En mi opinión, queda más compacto utilizando GregorianCalendar y Date :

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter your birthdate:");
System.out.println("Year: ");
int year = sc.nextInt();
System.out.println("Month: (1-12)");
int month = sc.nextInt()-1;
System.out.println("Day: ");
int day = sc.nextInt();
Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar();
calendar.setTime(new Date());
Calendar calendar2 = new GregorianCalendar(year,month,day);
long diffInMillis = calendar.getTimeInMillis()-calendar.getTimeInMillis();
System.out.println("I am  " + diffInMillis/3600000*24*365+" years, "+diffInMillis/3600000*24*30.4167+" months, "+diffInMillis/3600000*24+" days, "+ diffInMillis/3600000+" hours, "+ diffInMillis/60000+" minutes and "+diffInMillis/1000+ " seconds old");
```

Por supuesto, admitiendo el error planteado por Elenasys en el cálculo para los meses.

Comment: Solo un pequeño cambio. Usa `Calendar#getInstance` en lugar de `new GregorianCalendar`. Así, el calendario va a depender de la configuración del sistema. No todos los calendarios son gregorianos.

Comment: Adicional, cuidado con el valor de `month`. Según la documentación de ese constructor, el campo `month` está basado en 0, no en 1, por lo que si ingresan 12 como mes, entonces se contará como mes 0.

Answer (score 0):

A partir de tu código planteado, es un poco complicado tener un calculo exacto, por el hecho que tienes que revisar que meses son los que se tienen en el calculo y como sabes los meses pueden tener diferente cantidad de días.

Si tomamos el promedio de días que puede tener un mes que es `30.4167` en un año, se puede obtener el resultado (considerando un pequeño margen de error en el calculo).

```
...
...

      System.out.println("I am " + p.getYears() + " years, " + p.getMonths() + " months, " + p.getDays() + " days old.");       


      double diasAno = p.getYears() * 365; //Días obtenidos a partir de los años.
      double diasMes = p.getMonths() * 30.4167;//Días obtenidos a partir de los meses, se usa el promedio.
      double dias = p.getDays(); //días.


      //Obtiene los dias transcurridos.
      double diasTotales = diasAno + diasMes + dias;
      System.out.println("diasTotales " + diasTotales);

      //Obtiene horas, minutos y segundos a partir de los dias transcurridos.       
      long horas = TimeUnit.DAYS.toHours((int)diasTotales);
      long minutos = TimeUnit.DAYS.toMinutes((int)diasTotales);
      long segundos = TimeUnit.DAYS.toSeconds((int)diasTotales);                   

      System.out.println("I am  " + horas + " hours, " + minutos + ", minutes and " + segundos + " seconds old.");
```